# Can't select an iCloud Photo Stream for Screen Saver

Tags: macos, icloud, photos.app, photo-stream, screensaver

I used to choose an iCloud Photo Stream of mine for my screen saver. But now, when I go to my screen saver settings, there is no option to choose an iCloud Photo Stream, but only Apple's default screen savers.

Any ideas about how to sort it out?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Please check this image below
[image]

If this is not visible on your Mac (I've had the same issue after upgrading to Mavericks) please logout iCloud entirely (remove everything from your Mac) and log back in.

It will be visible now.

Comment: Actually I forgot to write it down to the question but I tried that before asking. Although I might give it another try.